# Transparency issue with pseudo-elements and background on unique button shape

Tags: html, css, transparency

I am attempting to have a unique button shape that is achieved using pseudo-elements become transparent on one end so the background will show through. If the background is set to a solid color, the desired result  is easily achieved because I can change the `::after` element to be the same color. Though, I'm struggling to come up with a solution if the background is an image or svg.

codepen: https://codepen.io/codingforthefuture/pen/YzKvGvq

I have the `::after` element set to white to demonstrate the problem, though you can change it to pink to see the desired result.

Problem occurs if you change the color of the pseudo-element to transparent, you see the other pseudo-element in its place. If you remove that pseudo-element you remove the border on that end for the shape.

```css
body{
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a .btn-flag {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.btn-flag strong{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: 10px;
}

.btn-flag {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 0.7rem;
      min-width: 200px;
      height: 35px;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      padding-top: 15px;
      position: relative;
      background: yellow;
      color: black;
      font-size: 7px;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-top: 1px solid red;
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
      border-left: 1px solid red;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      
    }

    .btn-flag::before,
    .btn-flag::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      left: 87%;
     /*should be transparent, Should acheive same effect as setting the color from #fff to pink but without knowing background set color, possible image or svg in background*/
      border-right: 26px solid #fff; 
      border-top: 26px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
    }

.btn-flag::before{
  /* other color to change, but changing gets rid of border on flag end */
  border-right: 26px solid red;
  border-top: 26px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 26px solid transparent;
  left: 86.5%;
}

/****************************************************/
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class="btn-flag">
    <strong>Example Text</strong>
  </a>
</body>
```

Comment: you should mention your zoom issue, or my old answer would be perfect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845095/8620333 since it's transparent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this! https://codepen.io/anonymousjoe/pen/wvwXJwz

Rather than trying to get pseudo elements to have crazy shapes and crazy borders, we can give each pseudo element the funny flag shape, and then fake the outlines on them using drop-shadows.

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 0 red) drop-shadow(1px 0 0 red);
```

Another option would be to use SVGs as background-images on each of the pseudo-elements positioned the same way I have them here.